# What does it mean to pass `undefined` to bind()?

Tags: javascript, bind

I was reading some documentation about the [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) function in javascript.

One of the examples starts off like this:

```
function list() {
  return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
}

var list1 = list(1, 2, 3); // [1, 2, 3]

//  Create a function with a preset leading argument
var leadingZeroList = list.bind(undefined, 37);

var list2 = leadingZeroList(); // [37]
```

So my question is:

What exactly does it means to pass `(undefined, 37)` to `bind()` here?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It means that you don't want `this` to refer to anything in the resulting bound function. In other words, it assures that when you call your bound function, `this` will be `undefined`.  Exactly why you'd do that of course depends on the code; lots of functions don't use `this` so it's a way of being tidy.

Note that in non-strict mode, it *may* be the case that the runtime will substitute the global object (`window` in a browser) for `undefined`, but I can find no spec that stipulates that behavior. In strict mode, no such substitution is performed.

Comment: When they say "preset leading argument", are they referring to the 37?( and not the `undefined` )

Comment: @BeeBand yes - the first argument to `bind()` is the value you want `this` to be set to when the resulting function is called. Subsequent parameters are passed in front of whatever else is passed at the point(s) of invocation.

Comment: `In other words, it assures that when you call your bound function, this will be undefined` This part is actually not true, `this` will point to `window`, same if you bind `null`.

Comment: @Baki that is only true in non-strict mode. If the `.bind()` is called in strict mode, the function will truly be bound to `undefined`.

Comment: The strict mode warning is important.

Answer (score 3):

The first parameter to `bind` specifies the `this` value inside the function. It can be used to convert it to a 'method' that acts on an object. However if you pass `undefined` it means it remains a function. So in the example you mentioned above there is no difference.